# How to correctly shape my CNN-LSTM input layer

Tags: python, keras

I have a data set with the shape (3340, 6). I want to use a CNN-LSTM to read a sequence of 30 rows and predict the next row's (6) elements. From what I have read, this is considered a multi-parallel time series. I have been primarily following this [machine learning mastery tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/) and am having trouble implementing the CNN-LSTM architecture for a multi-parallel time series.

I have used this function to split the data into 30 day time step frames

```
# split a multivariate sequence into samples
def split_sequences(sequences, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequences)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the dataset
        if end_ix > len(sequences)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :], sequences[end_ix, :]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)
```

Here is a sample of the data frames produced by the function above.

```
   # 30 Time Step Input Frame X[0], X.shape = (3310, 30, 6)
   [4.951e-02, 8.585e-02, 5.941e-02, 8.584e-02, 8.584e-02, 5.000e+00],
   [8.584e-02, 9.307e-02, 7.723e-02, 8.080e-02, 8.080e-02, 4.900e+01],
   [8.080e-02, 8.181e-02, 7.426e-02, 7.474e-02, 7.474e-02, 2.000e+01],
   [7.474e-02, 7.921e-02, 6.634e-02, 7.921e-02, 7.921e-02, 4.200e+01],
   ...

   # 1 Time Step Output Array y[0], y.shape = (3310, 6)
   [6.550e-02, 7.690e-02, 6.243e-02, 7.000e-02, 7.000e-02, 9.150e+02]
```

Here is the following model that I am using:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 1, activation='relu'), input_shape=(None, 30, 6)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(6))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

When I run model.fit, I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_59_input to have 
4 dimensions, but got array with shape (3310, 30, 6)
```

I am at a loss at how to properly shape my input layer so that I can get this model learning. I have done several `Conv2D` nets in the past but this is my first time series model so I apologize if there's an obvious answer here that I am missing.

Comment: You don't need TimeDistributed() wrappers for the Conv1D and Max Pooling1D layers. This is done intrinsically. I also don't get why you are using a Flatten layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove `TimeDistributed` from `Conv1D` and `MaxPooling1D`; 3D inputs are supported
- Remove `Flatten()`, as it destroys `timesteps`-`channels` relationships
- Add `TimeDistributed` to the last `Dense` layer, as `Dense` does not support `3D` inputs (returned by `LSTM(return_sequences=True)`; alternatively, use `return_sequences=False`)